# white sauce / bechamel - without lumps

Tags: sauce, bechamel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How not to mess up bechamel scauce](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/4381/how-not-to-mess-up-bechamel-scauce)

So you melt the butter and mix the flour in = easy
Adding the first bit of milk and making a paste = easy

Now getting from that to a sauce without lumps = tricky.

Other than cheating and just using a power whisk or putting the resulting mess through a sieve are there any other tips?

Comment: Hey, the linked duplicate should answer your question. It's better if we don't split the answers up between multiple threads so I am closing this as a duplicate.

Comment: Sorry I did a search, white sauce showed nothing and I misspelled bechamel. The search on here is pretty poor if it can't match bechEmel/bechAmel

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, you want to add as little milk as possible at first, whisking well, then very gradually add more milk as you whisk vigorously the entire time.  From your second line, I think you've got the "small amount" part covered.  If you're not already doing this, whisk as you pour - once you start adding milk, I recommend to not stop whisking until the milk is incorporated.

I was also told that you should use warm/hot milk (I give it a quick hit with the microwave) instead of cold.  That might be the difference that's causing yours to lump if you're already whisking very well.  I don't always heat my milk and still get a good consistency, but I also whisk like a madman.  I would recommend trying to the milk and see it if helps.